# AutoFS special map does not work

Tags: nfs, autofs

I'm trying to use an AutoFS special map [as referenced here](https://books.google.com/books?id=RPLqBwAAQBAJ&pg=PA300&lpg=PA300&dq=autofs%20special%20map&source=bl&ots=O3LbBvAZTv&sig=M9elleiSC5Tf7IckciN1Fa8n-3s&hl=en&sa=X&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=autofs%20special%20map&f=false).  Surprisingly, I've found little information about that on the Web. (This might be because the reference above seems to be the only one calling it a "special map"; noone else is using this terminology.)

Apparently the autofs service on the client should automatically run `/etc/auto.net` to find all available NFS servers.
Although I set up previously a NFS server on another machine (fully working, as a manual mount on the client machine works fine), nothing appears under `/net` on the client.

This is an excerpt of the `mount` command output on the client relative to the NFS service:

```
 /etc/auto.misc on /misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=6,pgrp=12862,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,indirect)
 -hosts on /net type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=13,pgrp=12862,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,indirect)
```

EDIT: Contents of `/etc/auto.master`:

```
/misc   /etc/auto.misc
/net    -hosts
+dir:/etc/auto.master.d
+auto.master
/-  /etc/auto.direct
```

Which steps should be followed to troubleshoot this?

Comment: Content of your `/etc/auto.master` please. It's possible you haven't uncommented the entry for `auto.net`